# Hide/remove element from blog post after a few days of it being posted

Tags: jquery, html, umbraco

I want to add a 'new' label to new blog posts on my website that will automatically disappear after a few days after the blog is posted. Any ideas how I could achieve this? My website uses the Umbraco CMS.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to edit the blog post template and add a couple of script lintes that compare the current datetime with the createtime of the blogpost

Example code (untested)

```
@{
   var difference = DateTime.Now - blog.CreateDate;
   if(difference.TotalDays <= 2){
      <span>show label</span>
   }
}
```